# Running ansible playbooks within ruby wrapper

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find a simple method of running an ansible playbook from within a ruby script.

My script checks various conditions, and - if those conditions a met - runs an ansible playbook.

I thought I could run the playbook via backticks using the kernel module. However I'm unsure how I could parse the output to tell if I had success. Does anyone have a method, wrapper or library to do this? Searching the web only resulted in information about how to deploy ruby with ansible playbooks, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the output of a command you need to use [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.0.preview2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html).

For example:

```
require 'open3'

output, status = Open3.capture2('ansible', '...')
```

Where you split out the arguments to the `ansible` command separately to avoid ugly shell-interpolation issues.

There's a variety of tools in the `Open3` module that help with things like streaming output, checking STDERR and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a dependency then you can use [tty-command](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-command):

```
require 'tty-command'

cmd = TTY::Command.new

result = cmd.run('ansible ...')

puts result.out.chomp
```